# wp-cron and woocommerce subscriptions killing performance

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cron, subscription

I wonder if replacing wp-cron by steeing my server cron tasks is going to work.
I have disabled cron on a test site i am trying to optimize and the performance increased a lot.
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Yes, it will work - here's [WordPress's instructions for driving WP Cron from the server cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/).

Comment: Or there are more complicated set ups e.g. I've seen a whole Linux service set up to run cron jobs for WordPress. But I can't find it now :-/